# read textfile line by line with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

HI I try to read a textfile line by line with JQuery.

I try it like this:

```
function load_file(file, element) {
    var lines = file.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        save(lines[i]);
    }
    $(element).load(file);

}
```

and the html file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JFunc.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


      <input type="button" value="load" onclick="load_file('../movie.txt', '#content_area');" />
    <div id="content_area"></div>

    </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

But the page remains empty.

I can read the file without line by line. But then it is one big line. And not line by line.

The text file looks like this:

> 1. The Shawshank Redemption
> 2. The Godfather
> 3. The Godfather: Part II
> 4. Pulp Fiction
> 5. The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
> 6. 12 Angry Men
> 7. Schindler’s List
> 8. The Dark Knight
> 9. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
> 10. Fight Club
> 11. Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back
> 12. One Flew Over the Cuckoo’s Nest
> 13. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
> 14. Inception
> 15. Goodfellas
> 16. Star Wars
> 17. Seven Samurai
> 18. The Matrix
> 19. Forrest Gump
> 20. City of God

Thank you

if I just do this:

```
function load_file(file, element) {
    //var lines = file.split("\n");

    //for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
    //    save(lines[i]);

    $(element).load(file);

}
```

the browser can read the file. But not every title on a single line

Comment: The variable `file` is the **string** `../movie.txt`, it is not the content of the file. If you to `'../movie.txt'.split('\n')` you get `['../movie.txt']` (which is not what you are looking for).

Comment: oke, but how to do it then?

Comment: If you want to read the file you should do another request to the server in order to get the content of that file. You can use `$.ajax` (or `$.get`) for that.

Comment: it's impossible to read the code in your comment. You better update the question with your code.

Comment: @Dekkel I don't understand what you mean. I did that.

Comment: Solved. I am glad

Answer (score 4):

I solved like this:

```
jQuery.get('movie.txt', function (data) {

    var lines = data.split("\n");

    $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
        $('#content_area').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');

    });
    console.log(lines);    
});
```

Comment: Good to see that you managed to solve it yourself :) got my vote for that!